# The allowence does not show the approved value with ERC20 token

Tags: solidity, erc-20

An ERC20 contract was deployed in `remix` and here is the `approve` console output:

```
status  true Transaction mined and execution succeed
 transaction hash   0x2b74bd0672c9140a016cd2c3cd2186624eca19dbd3876bb2ade23b6301bda04b 
 from   0x4B20993Bc481177ec7E8f571ceCaE8A9e22C02db 
 to FeiyunToken.approve(address,uint256) 0x2FbE968dF12A1265dFF6e8215EbF8D022FaD6B2b 
 gas    4000043 gas 
 transaction cost   26261 gas 
 execution cost 3389 gas 
 hash   0x2b74bd0672c9140a016cd2c3cd2186624eca19dbd3876bb2ade23b6301bda04b 
 input  0x095...00014 
 decoded input  { "address spender": "0x0a7180a063D06AfC0a5C69829b71062B6a4FED56", "uint256 amount": { "type": "BigNumber", "hex": "0x14" } } 
 decoded output { "0": "bool: true" } 
 logs   [ { "from": "0x2FbE968dF12A1265dFF6e8215EbF8D022FaD6B2b", "topic": "0x8c5be1e5ebec7d5bd14f71427d1e84f3dd0314c0f7b2291e5b200ac8c7c3b925", "event": "Approval", "args": { "0": "0x4B20993Bc481177ec7E8f571ceCaE8A9e22C02db", "1": "0x0a7180a063D06AfC0a5C69829b71062B6a4FED56", "2": "20", "owner": "0x4B20993Bc481177ec7E8f571ceCaE8A9e22C02db", "spender": "0x0a7180a063D06AfC0a5C69829b71062B6a4FED56", "value": "20" } } ]  
 value  0 wei
```

It approves 20 tokens with owner `0x4B20993Bc481177ec7E8f571ceCaE8A9e22C02db` and spender `0x0a7180a063D06AfC0a5C69829b71062B6a4FED56`. The `allowance[owner][spender]` shall return 20 token. Here is the allowance console output:

```
transaction hash    0x87c7e8307b666554f312968e45af58ac42cd3df7469c3bf523d7d6bff6e05ae2 
 from   0x4B20993Bc481177ec7E8f571ceCaE8A9e22C02db 
 to FeiyunToken.allowance(address,address) 0x2FbE968dF12A1265dFF6e8215EbF8D022FaD6B2b 
 transaction cost   25564 gas (Cost only applies when called by a contract) 
 execution cost 1476 gas (Cost only applies when called by a contract) 
 hash   0x87c7e8307b666554f312968e45af58ac42cd3df7469c3bf523d7d6bff6e05ae2 
 input  0xdd6...fed56 
 decoded input  { "address owner": "0x4B20993Bc481177ec7E8f571ceCaE8A9e22C02db", "address spender": "0x0a7180a063D06AfC0a5C69829b71062B6a4FED56" } 
 decoded output { "0": "uint256: 0" } 
 logs   []
```

It actually return `0` by `allowance`. Why the `allowance` is not `20`?

UPDATE: the `allowance` is implemented as:

```
import "@openZeppeline/ERC20"
contract ERC20Token is ERC20 {
....
function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        super.allowance(owner,spender);
    }
 }
```

However if calling directly the `allowance` implementation in `openZeppelin's ERC20.sol`, then the `allowance` returns `20` which is correct. It seems that `super.allowance()` causes the problem but not sure how and why.

Comment: You don't need to execute a transaction for function `allowance`, you can simply call it, as it doesn't change anything on the blockchain, and therefore doesn't require mining.

Comment: Adding `return` to override function `allowance` solves the problem.                                    return super.allowance(owner, spender);

Comment: The fact that you override this function means that you should have posted it to begin with! And again - you don't need to execute a transaction, you can simply call the function.

Comment: It is `call` instead `transact` on remix even though the log data shows otherwise.